# DoExpresscheckout not woking. it gives ACK failure

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am creating Expresscheckout API using PAYPAL. Set expresscheckout and get expresscheckout is working properly.  i get a tocken and payerid from these two steps. but when i goto DoExpresscheckout it gives me ACK failure.

```
DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType Object
(
    [DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseDetails] => 
    [FMFDetails] => 
    [Timestamp] => 2013-06-10T12:15:02Z
    [Ack] => Failure
    [CorrelationID] => a88b9b744676a
    [Errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => ErrorType Object
                (
                    [ShortMessage] => This Express Checkout session has expired.
                    [LongMessage] => This Express Checkout session has expired.  Token value is no longer valid.
                    [ErrorCode] => 10411
                    [SeverityCode] => Error
                    [ErrorParameters] => 
                )

        )

    [Version] => 98.0
    [Build] => 6341744
)
```

Does any one have correct code for `DoExpresscheckout` and what fields are require for make it Sucessful ??

Comment: Do you add the token/payer id to your doexpresscheckout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well paypal SDK is extremely simple. first if i were you i would install their example code and make sure it work on your server, from my previous experience there are rare cases where the SDK wont work and have php version issues.

Secondly after you're sure it works on your server, the chart flow is:

step 1.) SetExpressCheckout - with all the required fields like:billing address, products cart total etc...

if that was done correct you'll get a token,

step 2.) GetExpressCheckout - With the previously acquired token you'll do GetExpressCheckout passing the token, if that done correct you'll get:Ack, Token, PayerID, value, currencyID and basically an object that has all the purchase details.

step 3.) DoExpressCheckout - use the acquired fields from 2 to do a DoExpressCheckout as follows:

```
$path = $pluginfolder.'paypal/lib';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
require_once('services/PayPalAPIInterfaceService/PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.php');
require_once('PPLoggingManager.php');

$logger = new PPLoggingManager('DoExpressCheckout');

$token = urlencode( $getToken );
$payerId = urlencode(  $getPayerID);
$paymentAction = urlencode(  $paymentType);

$orderTotal = new BasicAmountType();
$orderTotal->currencyID = $getCurrencyID;
$orderTotal->value = $getOrderTotal;

$paymentDetails= new PaymentDetailsType();
$paymentDetails->OrderTotal = $orderTotal;
if(isset($notifyURL))
{
    $paymentDetails->NotifyURL = $notifyURL;
}

$DoECRequestDetails = new DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetailsType();
$DoECRequestDetails->PayerID = $payerId;
$DoECRequestDetails->Token = $token;
$DoECRequestDetails->PaymentAction = $paymentAction;
$DoECRequestDetails->PaymentDetails[0] = $paymentDetails;

$DoECRequest = new DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestType();
$DoECRequest->DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails = $DoECRequestDetails;


$DoECReq = new DoExpressCheckoutPaymentReq();
$DoECReq->DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest = $DoECRequest;

/*
* Trying to go a head with the payment and catching errors that might occure.
*/
try {
    /* wrap API method calls on the service object with a try catch */
    $DoECResponse = $paypalService->DoExpressCheckoutPayment($DoECReq);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    if(isset($ex)) {
        $ex_message = $ex->getMessage();
        $ex_type = get_class($ex);

        if($ex instanceof PPConnectionException) {
            $error[] = "Error connecting to " . $ex->getUrl();
            $errorCheck =  true;
        } else if($ex instanceof PPMissingCredentialException || $ex instanceof PPInvalidCredentialException) {
            $error[] = $ex->errorMessage();
            $errorCheck =  true;
        } else if($ex instanceof PPConfigurationException) {
            $error[] = "Invalid configuration. Please check your configuration file";
            $errorCheck =  true;
        }
    }
}
```

i hope that helps.